# How do I remove AddThis from the Product Description of WooCommerce products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce and Addthis don't play very nicely together unless you're happy for Addthis share buttons to be above and below your product description like this:

[image: unwanted sharing buttons]

There is no option available inside Woocommerce products to disable Addthis from these pages, so how do I remove the Addthis share buttons from the product description?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is to modify the template.

Any php page copied from the `plugins/woocommerce/templates` folder to your `themes/themename/woocommerce` folder will override the default behaviour.

In this case, copy `plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php` to `themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php`.

Then edit your new description.php file and change the final line from:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
```

AddThis have added a filter or something to the_content() but this is bypassed with get_the_content and the AddThis buttons disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! At last! I add the same problem. It turns out there's a tick box on the facebook like widget settings with the comment 'Enable Other Social Buttons'. Toggle to 'no' and the floating nuisance diseappears! You can check out this page for more: https://justperryblog.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/deleting-the-addthis-floating-link-bar-a-solution/